# How do I create a clickable button on a header image with html?

Tags: html

I would like to know how to create a clickable button in HTML format that sits on in the center of a  header image.

I have tried to use the button tags along with the href attribute along with the img tags to try to wrap the code around the desired image but it doesn't work. An example of the result that I am trying to achieve can be found in the header on [github.com](http://github.com).

Comment: A tip: you can view the source of any site/page, and learn from that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just want a button centered on a header image, or if there is an image that you want styled as part of the button. (Post a screenshot for clarity, maybe?) Here is a snippet that does the former.

```css
.header {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/640/200/');
  width: 640px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header button {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <button onclick="alert('You clicked me!');" id="myButton">Click me!</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello an welcome on SO!

First of all, you should always post some code, so we can see that you've tried something.

> i am trying to achieve can be found in the header on github.com

An easy way to look how it's build is to inspect the code of this element by using some of provided developer tools in your browser (**BUT PLEASE NOT IE**)

If you are new to HTML you also should try to follow some tutorials and read some necessary documentation (Can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML)) and sure you don't want to miss the fancy CSS stuff, so you should also check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS) out.

**Now to your question**

What GitHub uses for this "button" is an `<a>` Tag, with a `<span>` tag inside, which uses an Octocat icon as font.

**DEMO**

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.icon {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="icon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to use a div structure with a background image, giving it an explicit width and height, and set its position to `relative`. You then position the button over however you want inside the div. There are several ways to do this.

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ewafford/1eft7o5a/)